# InnoDB: Cannot open table

Tags: innodb, errors

Copied to file from (XAMPP) /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
 to /Applications/AMPPS/var (AMPPS)

But I having this error.

```
2017-01-25 18:01:55 1860 [Warning] InnoDB: Cannot open table pronc_wp/wp_users from the internal data dictionary of InnoDB though the .frm file for the table exists. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting.html for how you can resolve the problem.
```

Not only wp_users tables. All tables is give to me this error.

Comment: Can you post the results of the following? `mysqlcheck --databases wordpress wp_governor`

Comment: How can I do it? I am working on Localhost. I am using AMPPS.

Comment: i try this.

pronc_wp.wp_commentmeta
Error    : Table 'pronc_wp.wp_commentmeta' doesn't exist
status   : Operation failed

.... bla bla.

Comment: This sounds like a problem that you need access to the host that runs the MySQL instance to solve. Why did you feel the need to copy that file to the new location?